# Atmel SAM v71 XPlained - Can't work with Port C

Tags: c, arm, atmel

I just got an Atmel SAM V71 "XPlained Ultra" board and I tried to write a basic little app that toggles LED0 and LED1.  LED0 works just fine connected to PIO_PA23_IDX.   However, the documentation claims that LED1 is connected to PC09, and surprisingly, there are no header defines for anything related to PORT C.  I tried to fake it by simply defining my IO-Pin as (64+9), following the convention that 0-31 were Port A, 32-63 were Port B... etc..... but this still doesn't work.  What am I missing here?  Why does the documentation claim that LED1 is connected to a Port that doesn't seem to exist in the source headers?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the absence of PORTC #defines, using 64+pin# works *just fine*.  The original problem was misleading and it turns out there's a separate problem with reading the switch on the board (probably a pin set to an alternate function).  To control the output of Port C Pin 9, use the a pin index of 64+9 (73).